# Transmission parameter into <?= ?>

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

[image: i don't know why i miss code]

I have list `<?= total ?>` length 7 and I want get element in list push array different.

[image: error]

I'm running google app script and page error

> "ReferenceError: "k" is not defined. (line 328, file "Code")"

```
var tmp = [];

for(var k = 0; k < <?= total.length ?> ; k ++){

 tmp.push(<?= total[k] ?>);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scriptlets (`<?= ... ?>`) gets executed first before the client side script does. You might want to do this instead

```
var tmp = [];

<? for( var k = 0; k < total.length; k++ ){ ?>
      tmp.push(<?= total[k] ?>);
<? } ?>
```

Comment: thank you so much <3 <3 <3. it's run !!! so you can explain more clearly how to use "<?=". I don't understand how to use it

Comment: What `<?= ... ?>` does is print the value given in the scriptlet. You can find more information [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates).